# Which standardization for lasso and dependent variable

Tags: lasso, regularization

What kind of standardization of the predictor matrix is needed for lasso?

let y be the response variable

is it (x-mean(x)/sd(x))  OR  (x-mean(x)/sd(y))?

Also does lasso require you to standardize the y response variable? This link says you need to standardize both y and x: https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/data-science/ridge/#

"Both the independent and dependent variables require standardization through subtraction of their averages and a division of the result with the standard deviations."

Comment: the double standardization you're referring to would be implemented as $x \gets \frac{x-\mu_x}{\sigma_x}$ and $y \gets \frac{y-\mu_y}{\sigma_y}$.

Answer (score 1):

It's $(x-\operatorname{mean}(x))/\operatorname{std}(x)$, operations performed feature-wise: you want to make the features going into the lasso have the same scale, here measured by having standard deviation of 1.

Lasso does not require the target to be scaled, but it might be helpful.  To every model on the original-scale $y$:

$$ y = c_0 + c_1 x_1 + \dotsb + c_n x_n $$

there is a corresponding model on the scaled $y$ targets:

$$ \frac{y-\bar{y}}{\sigma_y} = \frac{(c_0-\bar{y})}{\sigma_y} + \frac{c_1}{\sigma_y} x_1 + \dotsb + \frac{c_n}{\sigma_y} x_n .$$

The MSE of the two models are related by a factor of $\sigma_y^2$, and the lasso penalties are related by a factor of $\sigma_y$.  Without scaling then, you can just scale the penalty factor $\lambda$ by the extra factor of $\sigma_y$ and the optimal coefficients for the two forms will be the same.  But, if you like $\lambda$ to be more independent of the dataset, then scaling the targets helps in that way.